# rails: Facebook comments button can't recognize different resources!

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, rest, comments

I try to implement a facebook comment box to my catalogue controller. Every catalogue entry should have his one facebook comments! The problem is that the fxml doesn't recognize different resources.

```
www.remme.com/catalogues
www.remme.com/catalogues/2
www.remme.com/catalogues/3
```

This seems to be the same page for facebook! How can I solve this?

Thanks,
Maecki

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the xid params of fb:comments and set it as your resource url. http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/comments